# Reflection to get the Delegate Information

Tags: c#, reflection

By executing the following i can get the information about methods

```
Type t=typeof(someType);

MemberInfo[] mInfo = t.GetMethods();
```

how to get information about delegates declared inside a type?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Call [`Type.GetNestedTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/493t6h7t.aspx) to get the nested types and filter them by being a delegate (check whether they inherit from [`System.MulticastDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.aspx)):

```
static IEnumerable<Type> GetNestedDelegates(Type type)
{
    return type.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
               .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(MulticastDelegate));
}
```