# Recognize delegates with MethodInfo

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I want to identify all delegates of a class using reflection. I don't want to invoke them, just identify. I suppose that I may use `getMembers()` like that :

```
Type t = myType;
MemberInfo[] mia = t.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic).OrderBy(item => item.Name).ToArray();
foreach (MemberInfo m in mia)
{
    //Find delegates
}
```

**EDIT** : Delegate example :

```
class ClassTest
{
    public delegate void SampleEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
}
```

It's possible with this method, or another ?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: What do you mean by all delegates?

Comment: What do you mean by "delegates of a class"? Can you give an example of what you're trying to detect?

Comment: Do you want to identify delegate types that matches the method signatures ? Or delegates defined inside your class ? Your question is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: Even with the example it doesn't make much sense. Do you want to find nested types that are delegates?

Comment: This should work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954782/reflection-to-get-the-delegate-information

Comment: This should work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954782/reflection-to-get-the-delegate-information

Comment: This should work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954782/reflection-to-get-the-delegate-information

Comment: Yes, In this case I think that is a nested type.

Comment: This should work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954782/reflection-to-get-the-delegate-information

Comment: One post should be enough ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A delegate is just a (special, compiler-generated) class, that may be declared inside a class as a nested type - but bear in mind that they may also be declared directly in a namespace, like normal classes.

This will find you all nested types in a given type `t`, that are delegates:

```
private IEnumerable<Type> DelegatesDefinedInType(Type t) 
{
    var nestedTypes = t.GetNestedTypes();    
    return nestedTypes.Where(typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom);
}
```